# Mapbox GL AddLayer: Where are the icon images coming from

Tags: mapbox-gl

A lot of the examples always load the icon image like this (For example here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/):

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}-15",
        "text-field": "{title}",
        "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
        "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
        "text-anchor": "top"
    }
});
```

Where is this icon stored and how can I link to a local png or svg? Or how can I put my own `markers`into source? The example is not very well documented.

Comment: Did you check the 'style reference' section of the API docs?

Comment: It is not very well explained in my opinion. Would love to see a well explained working example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you follow the examples, you only get the sprites that load with your particular style's sprite sheet, which is NOT NECESSARILY a 1 to 1 match with any other style.

ex: emerald-v8 has NO "icon-image":"harbor-15" like the example that uses streets-v8.

To see the list of available sprites from corresponding styles:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles/tree/master/sprites

I can choose the "harbor" icon from their emerald-v8 repository like so:

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "pointclick",
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'pointclick',
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "harbor_icon",
        "icon-size":1.5
    },
    "paint": {}
});
```

Here is the resource that helped me pull it all together, and it explains how to create your own icons: https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers/#locate-mapbox-styles-images

*EDIT:*

Basically, to add one of your own icons, go into Mapbox studio, create your own style, or edit one of theirs. Simply add one of your own SVGs, then that icon will become available to you into your custom sprite sheet.[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also use external/generated icons as `icon-image` if you use `map.loadImage()` and `map.addImage()` first.

Examples:

[Add an icon to the map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/)

[Add a generated icon to the map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-generated/)

Answer (score -1):

As it is said in [sprite docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sprite/):
Pass `"sprite": "https://link"` to your style, where `link` is link to json genereted with [spritezero-cli](https://github.com/mapbox/spritezero-cli). spritezero-cli generated png sprite from list of your icons in svg format. That you can use icons in symbol layers as `'icon-image'`.